# Load JS within SugarCRM 7.x Instance

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm

I need to load a JavaScript file on the Contacts EditView. How can I do this? I tried it via JSGroupings but it loads before the form is loaded and I don't want it that way. I also tried it with record.js but that's not working either.

I'm very new and noob to SugarCRM 7 so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause/loop your js script until SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress() returns false. With all Ajax calls ended the form should be loaded.

Comment: Thanks.I have used following code
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    alert('Document Loaded!')
    SUGAR.App.on('app:start', function(){
        alert('app Loaded!');
       alert(SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress());
       $( "#first_name" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    });
});  But it loads before elements are loaded though SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress() returns false Test is not appended as in code